Does the C++ standard forbid reusing storage without destroying?
Which parts of a modern C++ standard (C++20 or C++23 are fine) say whether it's okay to reuse an object's storage without running its destructor using placement new?
alignas(T) std::byte storage[sizeof(T)];
T* p = new (storage) T(...);
p = new (storage) T(...)
p->~T();

If it's not allowed in general, are there any conditions this is allowed, e.g. if T has a trivial destructor?

The C++20 standard says explicitly in [basic.life]/5 that it's okay to reuse storage without calling the destructor:

For an object of a class type, the program is not required to call the destructor explicitly before the storage which the object occupies is reused or released; however, if there is no explicit call to the destructor or if a delete-expression is not used to release the storage, the destructor is not implicitly called and any program that depends on the side effects produced by the destructor has undefined behavior.

For types with a trivial destructor this seems totally innocuous: their destructors by definition have no side effects, so the program can't depend on them.
For an arbitrary type it doesn't seem like this is a particularly good idea, but I can't find any language that says it's UB independent of what the rest of the program does.

Seems ok to overwrite objects w/o trivial destructors. Here's an example of a class that allocates using new which is overwritten without first destroying it leaving behind an object  in the heap. However, that object is then deleted later. This all happens in a constexpr eval . Removing the delete will cause compile failure. examples Leaving behind a chunk of heap memory isn't UB. Just bad practice.

Yeah, the intent of my answer is to say "nothing defines it as UB, but it's probably not good form in general". For specific types it may be fine, and for types with a trivial destructor it's provably fine because the destructor can't be observed anyway.

The technique can be useful at times. For instance replacing const ptrs and references in an object. Perfectly legal way to reseat a reference. Useful in aggregates to maintain const correctness since the elements are required to be public. Just use destroy_at first for those with non-trivial dtors.
